# Resize UITableView when it is not in the frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm working on a dictionary app based on an open source project. I would like to resize the `UITableView` to different height. This is the [screenshot](https://github.com/zonble/MOEDict/blob/master/Screenshots/iPhone1.png) of the app. Upon clicking the `searchbar`, `UITableView` will [appear below](https://github.com/zonble/MOEDict/blob/master/Screenshots/iPhone2.png). I check from [the code](https://github.com/zonble/MOEDict/blob/master/MOEDict/MDViewController.m), there is no code which attach the `UITableView`. I'm expecting there is `self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake`.

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, 44.0);
    self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
    self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - 64.0);
```

How the `UITableView` is attached to the view and how should I modify the height?

Comment: have you tried using the delegates of UISearchController?

Comment: The code is using searchDisplayController. How should I modify the height?

Comment: To modify the height you can create an nslayoutconstraint in your code and you can change it programatically. Example : `self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 220`

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple delegates that you can work with [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchdisplaydelegate)

One that can help you is `- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar`. In here you can change the size of the tableView and on `- (BOOL)searchBarShouldEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` hide the tableView again if you wish to

Comment: Ok, but the tableview never declared in property. How should I change the height?

Comment: you need to initiate the tableView, try making it a property so that you can call it when you wish to